# mvc website time to first byte very slow

Tags: web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

Anyone any idea on why an mvc website can be so slow on a time to first byte. The home page has no database connections, I've have just uploaded a mvc home page and its takes about 15 seconds to load, copy the url and paste in another browser window and takes just as long.

But put an index.html on the end and it loads in a flash.

url removed

If I copy the source code and paste into notepad and create html page, very fast

Site runs on windows IIS 7.5

I cannot really upload full site while trying to find the problem

Thanks
George

---------------------Home page code---------------

```
using DevTrends.MvcDonutCaching;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using Web.UI.ModelHelpers.Validation;

namespace Web.UI.Controllers
    {
    //[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
    public class HomeController : Controller
        {
       // [DonutOutputCache(CacheProfile = "Cache1Hour")]
        public ActionResult Index()
            {
            ViewBag.Title = "Active Tourist Search Engine";
            return View();
            }

        public PartialViewResult pvSearchForm(string Option, string Page)
            {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Option) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Page))
                {
                var model = new SearchEngineValidation
                {
                    Option = "Web",
                    Page = "1",
                    ISB = "1",
                };
                ViewBag.SearchButtonText = "Web";
                return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/pvSearchForm.cshtml", model);
                }
            else
                {
                var model = new SearchEngineValidation
                {
                    Option = Request.QueryString["Option"],
                    Page = Request.QueryString["Page"],
                    ISB = "0",
                };
                ViewBag.SearchButtonText = model.Option;
                return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/pvSearchForm.cshtml", model);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You will notice I have commented out the caching, with caching on load fast, but I'm trying to find underlying problem

Output from Fiddler

```
Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      323        (headers:323; body:0)
Bytes Received:  6,325      (headers:270; body:6,055)

ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
--------------
ClientConnected:    13:30:39.611
ClientBeginRequest: 13:30:39.611
GotRequestHeaders:  13:30:39.611
ClientDoneRequest:  13:30:39.611
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         1ms
TCP/IP Connect: 38ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    13:30:39.651
FiddlerBeginRequest:    13:30:39.651
ServerGotRequest:   13:30:39.652
ServerBeginResponse:    13:30:54.102
GotResponseHeaders: 13:30:54.102
ServerDoneResponse: 13:30:54.102
ClientBeginResponse:    13:30:54.154
ClientDoneResponse: 13:30:54.154

    Overall Elapsed:    00:00:14.5428318
```

Comment: _Something_ slow must be happening server-side.  There's no client-side indication of anything wrong, other than taking 14 seconds to respond.  What else is the server-side code doing?  Is there something in the controller action?  In a base controller class?  In a global request handler?

Comment: post the code in the controller action

Comment: added controller code

Comment: On every test, its takes about 14 seconds

Comment: Hi David no nothing, its just a simple controller I had turned off SQL but that had no effect, If i was just the 1st hit then I could understand it, but its every hit even seconds apart. My VPS has 2GB memory and 1 core processer, also the delay is always about 14-15 seconds never more or less

Comment: Is it possible you are running in debug mode? If so, see if you experience similar performance issues when running with a release configuration compilation.

Comment: @CareerChange got any luck to improve ttfb?